# How to reduce the gap in my document?

Tags: gap

I have got random weird gaps in my overleaf report like this
[image]

Unfortunately I can't give you the full document because it is my dissertation. However, below is my document set-up (according to the outline from my uni)

https://www.overleaf.com/15330810yfvwwgcscwty#

Thanks in advance!

Comment: It's hard to tell without a compilable example, but maybe removing the empty line before `\begin{align}` will help.

Comment: You could try replacing `\flushbottom` with `\raggedbottom`.

Comment: I'm guessing there's a large (in height) Equation 6.6 that shows up shortly after Equation 6.5? If it can't fit on a the same page as Equations 6.3-6.5, you'll get these kinds of gaps.

Comment: I tried deleting \flushbottom and it works. Thanks!